# Hyperledger Fabric - Chaincode Invoke Version (for client version variations)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

The `peer chaincode invoke` command does not accept a version flag:

```
$ peer chaincode invoke --help
Invoke the specified chaincode. It will try to commit the endorsed transaction to the network.

Usage:
  peer chaincode invoke [flags]

Flags:
  -C, --channelID string               The channel on which this command should be executed
      --connectionProfile string       Connection profile that provides the necessary connection information for the network. Note: currently only supported for providing peer connection information
  -c, --ctor string                    Constructor message for the chaincode in JSON format (default "{}")
  -h, --help                           help for invoke
  -n, --name string                    Name of the chaincode
      --peerAddresses stringArray      The addresses of the peers to connect to
      --tlsRootCertFiles stringArray   If TLS is enabled, the paths to the TLS root cert files of the peers to connect to. The order and number of certs specified should match the --peerAddresses flag
      --waitForEvent                   Whether to wait for the event from each peer's deliver filtered service signifying that the 'invoke' transaction has been committed successfully
      --waitForEventTimeout duration   Time to wait for the event from each peer's deliver filtered service signifying that the 'invoke' transaction has been committed successfully (default 30s)

Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --certfile string                     Path to file containing PEM-encoded X509 public key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --clientauth                          Use mutual TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --connTimeout duration                Timeout for client to connect (default 3s)
      --keyfile string                      Path to file containing PEM-encoded private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --logging-level string                Default logging level and overrides, see core.yaml for full syntax
  -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
      --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when validating the TLS connection to the orderer.
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --transient string                    Transient map of arguments in JSON encoding
```

According to the comments on [this issue](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-2957), the lack of a version option is intentional.

However, if I have clients using a variety of interface versions, would I not also want to maintain old chaincode versions to accept those old client data formats?

I understand that I can filter the client data in my server-side programs before sending `invoke` to the peer, but it seems that allowing multiple chaincode versions would allow for more flexibility.  Can we expect a version option for `chaincode invoke` sometime in the future?